# Getting input from 50+ check boxes on a web form

Tags: php, javascript, html

Think of the form I am working on as a type of survey. It has 50+ possible conditions which can all be checked - or one. Just like any form I need to be able to post the results to a MySQL database. I am trying to figure the best method to get the input from all these checkboxes without having to create individual columns for each one (unless that is considered best practice).

So here is what I was thinking could work. Assign the checkboxes name numerically from 1-N. Then iterate through every checkbox checking it's state. Then instead of making a column for each checkbox - use one column and concatenate some kind of identifier for each.

Psuedocode

```
For checkbox in N:
    check state of N:
        if N is checked:
            concatenated string += idenifier(N)
```

Is this method a good way of doing it, or do you have other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the worst way of doing it. There are lots of things wrong with your proposed solution - but rather than try to make a silk purse from a sow's ear....

The only sensible way to do it in a relational database would be to have each checkbox result stored in its own row in the table. So you might have something like:

```
response {
   id auto_increment-,
   user_id references data elsewhere,
   ...
   primary key (id)
}

answers {
   response_id references response.id,
   checkbox_id references available_checkboxes.id,
   value_selected,
   primary key(response_id, check_box id)
}
```

Then you can also describe what the checkboxes represent:

```
available_checkboxes {
    id auto_increment;
    option_text varchar(40);
}
```

And build different questionnaires....customize the data gathering....and more

Comment: so one submission of the form would have one row with every column being a checkbox and the state of the chexbox?

Comment: Also why exactly is my method the worst way?

Comment: no, he's saying one submission would have many rows, with each row describing the state of exactly one checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't really about your form, it's about how to store your data.  It sounds like you'd like to store what might be considered a sparse matrix, ie you only want to store non-empty values. Have a look at the [EAV model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model). It's useful for data like this though it does have some major limitations  that you should make yourself aware of.

The table structure essentially makes columns into rows. Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE terms(
  term_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  termname varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  termvalue varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  assoc_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (assoc_id) REFERENCES maintable(main_id) ON DELETE CASCADE)
ENGINE=InnoDB
```

So you can call your checkboxes whatever you like.  When you process them, there will be 2 insert queries-  one to create the main record; and one to store the associated checkbox values.

```
INSERT INTO maintable(allfields, that, must, be, collected) VALUES (1,2,3,4,5);
//get last_insert_id(), we'll say main_id=7 this time

INSERT INTO mytable(termname, termvalue, assoc_id)
VALUES
('colour', 'blue', 7),
('feeling','happy', 7),
('schedule', 'daily', 7);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using separate columns in your DB should be determined by what the information is and how you plan to use it in the future.

If you are collecting info that is unique and could be used individually... that is, if each `checkbox` represents a value that could be compiled and then used apart from the others, then I would use separate columns.

**EDIT**

As per your comment...

> What would be the benefit of this method if I can get all the same
>   information from the concatenated string just as long as I have an
>   extra parsing step when getting the data?

I can think of several reasons:

1. You might not know how you want to retrieve the information in the future.  Placing it in one field would make it much more difficult to get, depending on how you wish to grab it.
2. Comparing the info becomes much harder, should you wish to do that.
3. Adding or removing `checkboxes` would also become much harder to maintain.

Comment: What would be the benefit of this method if I can get all the same information from the concatenated string just as long as I have an extra parsing step when getting the data?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to create a field varchar(50) in the MySQL table. Each position would be 0 or 1 depending if the associated checkbox was checked or not. So if the user checked boxes 1, 2, 5, 10, and 50, your string would look like:

```
$string = "1100100001000...0001" <- 50 positions
```

You could create the iteration in the receiving code to check if the checkbox was checked or not. If it was checked, add a "1" to the string, if it was not checked add a "0".

You could even create the string in your validation code in the client with javascript and pass the string already ready to be stored.

I have seen similar implementation used to track payments in an installment plan - each position in the string representing a monthly payment.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is exactly what I was envisioning. All it would need would be a lookup table which could be as simple as an xml file with all the values in the same order. If items 1,3,5 are checked read items 1,3,5 in table. I don't understand why this is considered bad.

Comment: @chancelkx: It's bad for a number of reasons. a) the mapping is separate from the data meaning that if you change the checkbox set you must change both the mapping and the data and keep them sync'd because your data is meaningless without the mapping; b) it's not normalized so you can't leverage any of the power of a relational database ie no indexing, no quick searching;

Comment: @chancelkx - why would you create rows (or columns) in a table when you can just as easily store one single string with all the information you need? I believe it would be less overhead this way. Don't you think?

Comment: @jdias: If chancelkx is using a relational db, a concatenated string is the least efficient method of storage there is. Say you want to query which records have checkbox23=1, you have to do a slow string parsing operation on *all* the records. But if you store the checkboxes as columns and use indices, it's a quick lookup. Or if your matrix is sparse, as is the case here, you can store your checkboxes as rows and with a few extra indices query almost as fast. Read up about data normalization in relational databases and you'll understand why mooshing the data into one field is a bad idea.

Comment: @dnagirl - actually you can retrieve all records that match "000...1...0000". No parsing string required. You just need to be a little creative in retrieving the data. I still think that a simple string is more efficient than a database where you will need to do joins, etc. What do you think?

Comment: @jdias: and what if you want all the records where checkbox23=1 and you don't care about the other fields? You're still doing a string match.  0101...1...0001 would be just as valid a record as 000...1...0000.  And if your queries get more complex, say `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE (c23=1 and c19=0 and c42=1) or (c50=1 not c2=0)`? How would you do that using your system?

Comment: @dnagirl - I see your point. For your queries we would probably need to do string manipulation. I up voted your comment... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the most clean way to doing that, it's to save form results as ORM-object, so checkboxes would be accessible like a form result's properties.

You could use Doctrine, or MongoDB for that.