# What is the best way to store a list of key values in one mysql column

Tags: php, mysql, json

I need to store data that can be variable, e.g. (data1='test1',data2='test2').

Is **json** the best way to do this ? or there is a better way?

Creating a table to contain the value, can't be done since the keys are dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it in JSON, yes. Just be sure to have a column data size that's long enough to accomodate your JSON strings.

You might want to have a look at `MongoDB` and other non-structured databases one day though, they're the more elegant way to do that.

Answer (score 7):

create a table where columns would be your keys and rows would contain values

And **never** use your database to store data like json. that's disgusting

Comment: +1 - take the time to normalise the data into a second table. It is simple to then recreate your comma delimited string again from a list.

Comment: Creating a table to contain the value, can't be done since the keys are dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a format for storing transfering values into/within javascript.

MySQL is a relational database and you should structure your data accordingly - i.e. it should be normalised. From the information you've provided it is impossible to say whether the right relational model for your data would across multiple columns or [across multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333714/getting-input-from-50-check-boxes-on-a-web-form/7333822#7333822).

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) to store your array in a single column. Use [`unserialize()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) when fetching the data from your table.